# The pre-Maimonidean half-tekheleth string

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, rambam, tzitzis, techeles

Are there any sources prior to the Rambam that suggest (even implicitly) that the *tekheleth* string is only half-dyed?

Comment: In his Birkath Yizhaq, R. Menahem Jenakh points to the Midrash about Qorah, אפשר טלית של מין אחר חוט אחד של תכלת פוטרתו, as a question on the views that require 2 strings

Comment: @wfb Interesting. But that just sounds like a rejection of Rashi and Tosafos' 2 full strings (and possibly of the Rambam's 1/2 string as well)...

Comment: @wfb (Which is I guess why you didn't post it as an answer.)

Comment: Yeah, he points out the Midrash works acc. to both the Rambam and the Ra'avad

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60687/759