# PreRishonic sources against the tekhelet half-string

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, techeles

What are the classical (pre-rishonic) sources explicitly or implicitly against the view of the Rambam that the tekheleth string is only half-dyed?

Comment: Check out the Sifrei in both Shlach and Ki Tetze, as well as the Gemara about finding Techelet in the Shuk and trying to decide if it was dyed Lishmah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. You don't happen to have links or at least specific references?

Comment: It's on Eruvin 96b. If Tekhelet for Tzitzit was half dyed, then wouldn't it have been obvious that it was Lishmah? Who half-dyes wool for other things? The Sifre is quoted here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67712/759 and doesn't seem to give 7/8 as an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Techeilet – Shittat haBa'alei Tosefot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67708/techeilet-shittat-habaalei-tosefot)