# Vilna Gaon Tekhelet Reasoning

Tags: vilna-gaon, techeles

What was the reasoning of the Vilna Gaon as to why he holds differently than the view of Rashi and Tosafot on the proper way of tying Tekhelet?

Comment: Accd to [Ptil Tekhelet](https://www.tekhelet.com/tying/vilna-gaon/), the approach of the Vilna Gaon is: "This method defines a chulyah as a group of three twists. It has 13 chulyot, and alternates white and Tekhelet between them, starting and ending with a chulyah of white. Those chulyot are distributed between five (double) knots with four chulyot between the top four knots and one white chulyah between the fourth and last knot." which is based upon his understanding of the Zohar as expressed in his commentary [Yahel Ohr to parshat Pinchas 227a](https://www.tekhelet.com/vilna-gaon-gra-words/)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67712/759